# AngularJS Apply filter to all inputs

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to apply a filter to all inputs or css-syntax selectable set of inputs? I have a lot of inputs and I am trying to add the filter number to each of them.

My current HTML

```
<table class="table">       
     <tbody>             
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="value" /></td>
            </tr>
     //many more inputs
     </tbody>
</table>
```

**To clarify:**

I'd like to change

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value" />
```

To something with the same result as (without adding the filter manually to each input):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="value | number:2" />
```

Comment: Please provide more details and code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this resource - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

I would imagine something like this is what you are looking for.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value" max="2" min="0" />
```

If you want to access this input fields validation, you need to wrap it inside a form.

At the bottom of the page that I sent you there is good example

Comment: Ah okay I see, I don't know of a way to do this. If you know how many inputs there is going to be you could save yourself time and put it all into an ng-repeat. Example `code<tr ng-repeat="inputs in inputs.length"><input type="text" ng-model="value | number:2" /></tr>`